# Ionic and ngCordova FileOpener2 Plugin issue

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am currently building an app with the Ionic Framework. And I need the ability to open a pdf. I am using the `ngCordova Plugin FileOpener2` for this task.

I get no error and a success message I prompted shows.

This is my controller :

```
module.controller('NewsCtrl', function ($cordovaFileOpener2) {

    $cordovaFileOpener2.open(
         '../img/Newsletter.pdf',
         'application/pdf'
     ).then(function() {
          console.log('Success');
     }, function(err) {
          console.log('Error' + err );
     });

});
```

I currently running it in the emulator with the command ionic emulate ios --livereload --target="iPhone-4s"

I have also tested it in an actual device with similar results.

I did stumble upon an error when changing some of the files and the livereload server refreshing the app on the tab with the controller and got the error :

> Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cordova.plugins.fileOpener2')

Answer (score 1):

No need for that complicated plugin! in our company app we need to be able to open pdf/s as well. we use https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf. It works wonderfuly. Here is what it look like on android.

[image]

It also works in ios: it also allows you to not have to leave the app to open a pdf. You can also pinch, zoom, rotate. Here is what the code looks like.

PDFViewer.html

```
 <ion-view>
    <div class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
        <button ng-click="$ionicGoBack()" class="button button-clear button-light icon-left ion-chevron-left">Go Back</button>
    </div>
    <div class="has-header">
        <ng-pdf template-url="components/pdfviewer/viewer.html" canvasid="pdf" scale="0.675">
        </ng-pdf>
    </div>
</ion-view>
```

Viewer.html

```
 <div ng-show="notLoaded" class=" center bar bar-subheader">
    <h1 class="title">Loading PDF...</h1>
</div>
<div class="tabs tabs-icon-left">
    <a class="tab-item" ng-click="goPrevious()">
        <i class="icon ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Prev
    </a>
    <a class="tab-item" ng-click="goNext()">
        <i class="icon ion-arrow-right-c"></i> Next
    </a>
</div>

<ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" class="has-header">
    <canvas class="padding" id="pdf" class="rotate0"></canvas>
</ion-scroll>
```

viewer.controller.js

```
 //variable that shows and hides the pdf loading bar
$scope.notLoaded = true;

//grabs the pdfUrl
$scope.pdfUrl = ffService.pdfLink;

//sets the position of the pdf viewer controls
$scope.getNavStyle = function (scroll) {
    if (scroll > 100) return 'pdf-controls fixed';
    else return 'pdf-controls';
};

//do something on pdf progress
$scope.onProgress = function (progress) {

}

//do something once the pdf is loaded, I use this to show and hide
//the loading... header on android
$scope.onLoad = function () {
    $scope.notLoaded = false;
}

//error logger for pdf viewer
$scope.onError = function (error) {
    $scope.showCustomAlert('Something went wrong', '<div class="center">' + error + '</div>');
};
```

and then you just include the js file in your html and inject 'pdf' into your top level module

```
angular.module('ffApp', ['ionic', 'controllers', 'services', 'ngCordova', 'pdf', 'ngSanitize', 'ngImgCrop', 'chart.js', 'ionic.service.core', 'ionic.service.push']);
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot! I'll definitely be checking this out

Answer (score 0):

I may be late but to some one who is searching for an answer. This error is happening because the controller loads faster than the ionic. These plugins will be available only after `$ionicPlatform.ready()`. So call these plugins after after the platform gets ready.

Answer (score 0):

Just another very very...late answer.

I had the same issue...just because he plugin was not properly installed!
Removing and adding the ios platform again could help.

```
codorva platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```